# Doctrine 2 how can I know if delete query deleted some data or nothing got deleted?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.5, MySQL 5.6

I have a delete query in my ajax like:

```
$temp = $db->executeQuery("DELETE FROM user_ban_table WHERE user_id = " . $term . ");

if ($temp) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => $temp]);
}
```

This is working for delete the records, **but how can I check if records deleted or nothing happened?**

(searched online and have been reading their docs, still can't get a solution)